# Bash globstar matching after text

Tags: bash, unix, minimatch, shopt

I really can't understand why pattern `test**/*.ext` matches `test23/file.ext`, but doesn't match `test23/test/file.ext` and `test23/test/test/file.ext`.
Globstar should match all of this, shouldn't it?

Comment: I suggest to use `test*/**/*.ext`.

Comment: Yep, it is working, but I can't find out, how exactly `test**/*.ext` works

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their programming code. This is more of a cmd-line tool usage problem. http://superuser.com would be a more approriate forum. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: A globbing question is perfectly on topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's `man bash`:

> When the globstar shell option is enabled, and * is used in a pathname expansion context, two adjacent *s used **as a single pattern** will match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories. If followed by a /, two adjacent *s will match only directories and subdirectories.

Since your `**` is not a single pattern but rather a part of `test**`, it does not get the globstar treatment.